# memtest freezes, but otherwise system works OK (Debian)

Tags: debian, hardware, virtualbox

I have a Debian 11 x64 system (info below) that works OK in general, but `memtest` simply freezes. It's not that it shows any errors, it just stops at say 40% of the test done and becomes unreactive.

I've unplugged all of the 4 memory modules and tried them one by one with the same result.

I've noticed that due to my Virtualbox Windows VMs regularly crashing. That's the only replicable problem I can find on the system. `dmesg` doesn't output anything in particular apart from that:

```
[    4.685877] EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 1
[    4.712627] EDAC MC: Removed device 0 for skx_edac Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0
[    4.997329] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module skx_edac controller Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0 (INTERRUPT)
[    4.997336] EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 1
[    5.064602] EDAC MC: Removed device 0 for skx_edac Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0
[    5.529025] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module skx_edac controller Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0 (INTERRUPT)
[    5.529038] EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 1
[    5.533872] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    5.533883] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
[    5.533888] intel_rapl_common: DRAM domain energy unit 15300pj
[    5.568563] EDAC MC: Removed device 0 for skx_edac Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0
[    5.945331] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module skx_edac controller Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0 (INTERRUPT)
[    5.945338] EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 1
[    5.964568] EDAC MC: Removed device 0 for skx_edac Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0
[    6.153759] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module skx_edac controller Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0 (INTERRUPT)
[    6.153773] EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 1
[    6.184555] EDAC MC: Removed device 0 for skx_edac Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0
[    6.253825] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module skx_edac controller Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0 (INTERRUPT)
[    6.253840] EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 1
[    6.284599] EDAC MC: Removed device 0 for skx_edac Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0
[    6.345738] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module skx_edac controller Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0 (INTERRUPT)
[    6.345757] EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 1
[    6.376584] EDAC MC: Removed device 0 for skx_edac Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0
[    6.409120] igb 0000:06:00.0 eno1: igb: eno1 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[    6.409337] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
[    6.481324] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module skx_edac controller Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0 (INTERRUPT)
[    6.481337] EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 1
[    6.516619] EDAC MC: Removed device 0 for skx_edac Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0
[    6.581855] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module skx_edac controller Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0 (INTERRUPT)
[    6.581870] EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 1
[    6.600557] EDAC MC: Removed device 0 for skx_edac Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0
[    6.673544] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module skx_edac controller Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0 (INTERRUPT)
[    6.673565] EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 1
[    6.704593] EDAC MC: Removed device 0 for skx_edac Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0
[    6.773816] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module skx_edac controller Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0 (INTERRUPT)
[    6.773837] EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 1
[    6.808606] EDAC MC: Removed device 0 for skx_edac Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0
[    6.913167] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module skx_edac controller Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0 (INTERRUPT)
[    6.913182] EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 1
[    6.940595] EDAC MC: Removed device 0 for skx_edac Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0
[    6.993580] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module skx_edac controller Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0 (INTERRUPT)
[    6.993602] EDAC skx: ECC is disabled on imc 1
[    7.008595] EDAC MC: Removed device 0 for skx_edac Skylake Socket#0 IMC#0: DEV 0000:64:0a.0
```

I'm not sure if those are memory modules or something on motherboard failing. How can I diagnose that?

Most of the `lshw` output, I had to cut large swaths of it due to 30k character limitation:

```
titan
    description: Computer
    product: SYS-5039AD-I (Default string)
    vendor: Supermicro
    version: 0123456789
    serial: .....
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.1.1 dmi-3.1.1 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal family=Default string sku=Default string uuid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-AC1F6B660721
  *-core
    description: Motherboard
    product: C9X299-PGF
    vendor: Supermicro
    physical id: 0
    version: 1.01
    serial: ....
    slot: Default string
  *-firmware
    description: BIOS
    vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    physical id: 0
    version: 1.1
    date: 02/14/2018
    size: 64KiB
    capacity: 16MiB
    capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
    description: System Memory
    physical id: 1c
    slot: System board or motherboard
    size: 32GiB
 *-bank:0
   description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
   product: NO DIMM
   vendor: NO DIMM
   physical id: 0
   serial: NO DIMM
   slot: DIMMA1
 *-bank:1
   description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
   product: NO DIMM
   vendor: NO DIMM
   physical id: 1
   serial: NO DIMM
   slot: DIMMA2
 *-bank:2
   description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
   product: NO DIMM
   vendor: NO DIMM
   physical id: 2
   serial: NO DIMM
   slot: DIMMB1
 *-bank:3
   description: DIMM Synchronous [empty]
   product: NO DIMM
   vendor: NO DIMM
   physical id: 3
   serial: NO DIMM
   slot: DIMMB2
 *-bank:4
   description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
   product: HMA81GU7AFR8N-UH
   vendor: SK Hynix
   physical id: 4
   serial: ....
   slot: DIMMC1
   size: 8GiB
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
 *-bank:5
   description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
   product: 18ASF1G72AZ-2G3B1
   vendor: Micron
   physical id: 5
   serial: ...
   slot: DIMMC2
   size: 8GiB
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
 *-bank:6
   description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
   product: M391A1K43BB1-CRC
   vendor: Samsung
   physical id: 6
   serial: ...
   slot: DIMMD1
   size: 8GiB
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
 *-bank:7
   description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
   product: M391A1K43BB1-CRC
   vendor: Samsung
   physical id: 7
   serial: ....
   slot: DIMMD2
   size: 8GiB
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
    description: L1 cache
    physical id: 2f
    slot: L1 Cache
    size: 512KiB
    capacity: 512KiB
    capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
    configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
    description: L2 cache
    physical id: 30
    slot: L2 Cache
    size: 8MiB
    capacity: 8MiB
    capabilities: synchronous internal varies unified
    configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
    description: L3 cache
    physical id: 31
    slot: L3 Cache
    size: 11MiB
    capacity: 11MiB
    capabilities: synchronous internal varies unified
    configuration: level=3
  *-cpu
    description: CPU
    product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820X CPU @ 3.60GHz
    vendor: Intel Corp.
    physical id: 32
    bus info: cpu@0
    version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820X CPU @ 3.60GHz
    slot: CPU
    size: 1199MHz
    capacity: 4500MHz
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 100MHz
    capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single pti ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm mpx rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities cpufreq
    configuration: cores=8 enabledcores=8 threads=16
  *-pci:0
    description: Host bridge
    product: Sky Lake-E DMI3 Registers
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 100
    bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
    version: 04
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
 *-generic:0
   description: System peripheral
   product: Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 4
   bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msix pciexpress pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=ioatdma latency=0
   resources: irq:79 memory:90944000-90947fff
 *-generic:1
   description: System peripheral
   product: Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 4.1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:04.1
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msix pciexpress pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=ioatdma latency=0
   resources: irq:82 memory:90940000-90943fff
 *-generic:2
   description: System peripheral
   product: Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 4.2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:04.2
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msix pciexpress pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=ioatdma latency=0
   resources: irq:79 memory:9093c000-9093ffff
 *-generic:3
   description: System peripheral
   product: Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 4.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:04.3
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msix pciexpress pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=ioatdma latency=0
   resources: irq:82 memory:90938000-9093bfff
 *-generic:4
   description: System peripheral
   product: Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 4.4
   bus info: pci@0000:00:04.4
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msix pciexpress pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=ioatdma latency=0
   resources: irq:79 memory:90934000-90937fff
 *-generic:5
   description: System peripheral
   product: Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 4.5
   bus info: pci@0000:00:04.5
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msix pciexpress pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=ioatdma latency=0
   resources: irq:82 memory:90930000-90933fff
 *-generic:6
   description: System peripheral
   product: Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 4.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:04.6
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msix pciexpress pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=ioatdma latency=0
   resources: irq:79 memory:9092c000-9092ffff
 *-generic:7
   description: System peripheral
   product: Sky Lake-E CBDMA Registers
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 4.7
   bus info: pci@0000:00:04.7
   version: 04
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msix pciexpress pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=ioatdma latency=0
   resources: irq:82 memory:90928000-9092bfff
 *-generic:8 UNCLAIMED
   description: System peripheral
   product: Sky Lake-E MM/Vt-d Configuration Registers
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 5
   bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
   version: 04
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
 *-generic:9 UNCLAIMED
   description: System peripheral
   product: Sky Lake-E RAS
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 5.2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:05.2
   version: 04
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
 *-generic:10 UNCLAIMED
   description: PIC
   product: Sky Lake-E IOAPIC
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 5.4
   bus info: pci@0000:00:05.4
   version: 04
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress pm io_x_-apic bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:90951000-90951fff
 *-generic:11 UNCLAIMED
   description: System peripheral
   product: Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 8
   bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
   version: 04
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
 *-generic:12 UNCLAIMED
   description: Performance counters
   product: Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 8.1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:08.1
   version: 04
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   configuration: latency=0
 *-generic:13 UNCLAIMED
   description: System peripheral
   product: Sky Lake-E Ubox Registers
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 8.2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:08.2
   version: 04
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
 *-communication
   description: Communication controller
   product: 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 16
   bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
   resources: irq:81 memory:9094d000-9094dfff
 *-sata
   description: SATA controller
   product: 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 17
   bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
   logical name: scsi1
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
   configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
   resources: irq:62 memory:90948000-90949fff memory:9094c000-9094c0ff ioport:4050(size=8) ioport:4040(size=4) ioport:4020(size=32) memory:9094b000-9094b7ff
 *-disk
   description: ATA Disk
   product: ST4000NM0035-1V4
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sda
   version: TN04
   serial: ....
   size: 3726GiB (4TB)
   capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
   configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=9176314b-cdd6-4a53-99e3-1fc255958b93 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
    *-volume:0
  -pci:0
   description: PCI bridge
   product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #17
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1b
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
   version: f0
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=pcieport
   resources: irq:24
 *-pci:1
   description: PCI bridge
   product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #19
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1b.2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.2
   version: f0
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=pcieport
   resources: irq:25 memory:90800000-908fffff
 *-usb
   description: USB controller
   product: ASM2142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
   vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi msix pm pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
   resources: irq:18 memory:90800000-90807fff
    *-usbhost:0
  product: xHCI Host Controller
  vendor: Linux 5.10.0-15-amd64 xhci-hcd
  physical id: 0
  bus info: usb@3
  logical name: usb3
  version: 5.10
  capabilities: usb-2.00
  configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
    *-usb
  description: USB hub
  product: Hub
  vendor: ATEN International Co., Ltd
  physical id: 2
  bus info: usb@3:2
  version: 1.00
  capabilities: usb-1.10
  configuration: driver=hub maxpower=100mA slots=4 speed=12Mbit/s
    *-usb
  description: Keyboard
  product: HDMI KVM V1.2.114
  vendor: ATEN Advance Tech Inc.
  physical id: 1
  bus info: usb@3:2.1
  version: 1.00
  capabilities: usb-1.10
  configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
    *-usbhost:1
  product: xHCI Host Controller
  vendor: Linux 5.10.0-15-amd64 xhci-hcd
  physical id: 1
  bus info: usb@4
  logical name: usb4
  version: 5.10
  capabilities: usb-3.10
  configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=10000Mbit/s
 *-pci:2
   description: PCI bridge
   product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #21
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1b.4
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.4
   version: f0
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=pcieport
   resources: irq:26 memory:90700000-907fffff
 *-storage
   description: Non-Volatile memory controller
   product: NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961/SM963
   vendor: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress msix nvm_express bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:90700000-90703fff
 *-pci:3
   description: PCI bridge
   product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #1
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1c
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
   version: f0
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=pcieport
   resources: irq:27 memory:90600000-906fffff
 *-usb
   description: USB controller
   product: ASM2142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
   vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi msix pm pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:90600000-90607fff
    *-usbhost:0
  product: xHCI Host Controller
  vendor: Linux 5.10.0-15-amd64 xhci-hcd
  physical id: 0
  bus info: usb@5
  logical name: usb5
  version: 5.10
  capabilities: usb-2.00
  configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
    *-usb
  description: Audio device
  product: Plantronics C320-M
  vendor: Plantronics
  physical id: 2
  bus info: usb@5:2
  version: 1.35
  serial: ...
  capabilities: usb-2.00 audio-control
  configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
    *-usbhost:1
  product: xHCI Host Controller
  vendor: Linux 5.10.0-15-amd64 xhci-hcd
  physical id: 1
  bus info: usb@6
  logical name: usb6
  version: 5.10
  capabilities: usb-3.10
  configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=10000Mbit/s
 *-pci:4
   description: PCI bridge
   product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #4
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1c.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
   version: f0
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=pcieport
   resources: irq:28 memory:90000000-904fffff
 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: AQC108 NBase-T/IEEE 802.3bz Ethernet Controller [AQtion]
   vendor: Aquantia Corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 02
   serial: ....
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress pm msix msi vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atlantic driverversion=5.10.0-15-amd64 firmware=1.5.58 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:19 memory:90440000-9044ffff memory:90450000-90450fff memory:90000000-903fffff memory:90400000-9043ffff
 *-pci:5
   description: PCI bridge
   product: 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1c.4
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
   version: f0
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=pcieport
   resources: irq:29 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:90500000-905fffff
 *-isa
   description: ISA bridge
   product: X299 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: isa bus_master
   configuration: latency=0
 *-memory UNCLAIMED
   description: Memory controller
   product: 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
   capabilities: bus_master
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:90924000-90927fff
 *-multimedia
   description: Audio device
   product: 200 Series PCH HD Audio
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
   resources: irq:90 memory:90920000-90923fff memory:90900000-9090ffff
 *-serial
   description: SMBus
   product: 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.4
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:9094a000-9094a0ff ioport:4000(size=32)
  *-generic:0 UNCLAIMED
    description: System peripheral
    product: Sky Lake-E VT-d
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 1
    bus info: pci@0000:16:05.0
    version: 04
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pciexpress cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
  *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
    description: System peripheral
    product: Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 2
    bus info: pci@0000:16:05.2
    version: 04
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pciexpress cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
  *-generic:2 UNCLAIMED
    description: PIC
    product: Sky Lake-E IOxAPIC Configuration Registers
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 4
    bus info: pci@0000:16:05.4
    version: 04
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pciexpress pm io_x_-apic bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:92300000-92300fff
  *-generic:3 UNCLAIMED
  *-generic:31 UNCLAIMED
    description: System peripheral
    product: Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 1e.4
    bus info: pci@0000:16:1e.4
    version: 04
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    configuration: latency=0
  *-generic:32 UNCLAIMED
    description: System peripheral
    product: Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 1e.5
    bus info: pci@0000:16:1e.5
    version: 04
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    configuration: latency=0
  *-generic:33 UNCLAIMED
    description: System peripheral
    product: Sky Lake-E PCU Registers
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 1e.6
    bus info: pci@0000:16:1e.6
    version: 04
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    configuration: latency=0
  *-pci:1
    description: PCI bridge
    product: Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port A
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 101
    bus info: pci@0000:64:00.0
    version: 04
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pci msi pciexpress pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
    configuration: driver=pcieport
    resources: iomemory:2000b0b00-2000b0aff irq:31 ioport:b000(size=4096) memory:b2000000-b30fffff ioport:a0000000(size=301989888)
 *-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:65:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:95 memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:b000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
 *-multimedia
   description: Audio device
   product: GP102 HDMI Audio Controller
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:65:00.1
   version: a1
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
   resources: irq:91 memory:b3080000-b3083fff
  *-generic:34 UNCLAIMED
    description: System peripheral
    product: Sky Lake-E VT-d
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 8
    bus info: pci@0000:64:05.0
    version: 04
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pciexpress cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
  *-generic:35 UNCLAIMED
    description: System peripheral
    product: Sky Lake-E RAS Configuration Registers
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 9
    bus info: pci@0000:64:05.2
    version: 04
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pciexpress cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
  *-generic:36 UNCLAIMED
    description: PIC
    product: Sky Lake-E IOxAPIC Configuration Registers
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 10
    bus info: pci@0000:64:05.4
    version: 04
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pciexpress pm io_x_-apic bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:b3100000-b3100fff
  *-generic:37
    description: System peripheral
    product: Sky Lake-E Integrated Memory Controller
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 11
    bus info: pci@0000:64:08.0
    version: 04
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pciexpress cap_list
    configuration: driver=skx_uncore latency=0
    resources: irq:0
  *-pci:2
    description: PCI bridge
    product: Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port D
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 3
    bus info: pci@0000:b2:03.0
    version: 04
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pci msi pciexpress pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
    configuration: driver=pcieport
    resources: irq:33 ioport:f000(size=4096) memory:fa000000-fb0fffff ioport:e0000000(size=301989888)
 *-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GV100 [TITAN V]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:b3:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:96 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:f000(size=128) memory:fb000000-fb07ffff
 *-multimedia
   description: Audio device
   product: NVIDIA Corporation
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:b3:00.1
   version: a1
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
   resources: irq:92 memory:fb080000-fb083fff
  *-generic:63 UNCLAIMED
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to throw some troubleshooting ideas. Likely issues in order.
Motherboard, Power Supply, software.

1. Try one memory module at a time in different slots. Mobo book tells you what slot to use for 1 module, but could have a bad mobo, so try 2 module configuration.
2. remove any extra PC cards, and plugged USB while troubleshooting (just keyboard, mouse and on board video card if available)
3. check if any firmware update to motherboard
4. try lower memory clock speed
5. try Live USB Ubuntu 20.04 or 18.04 with an older kernel
6. try different benchmark, testers, like Hardinfo, sysbench and SuperPi
7. Poorly grounded motherboard or loose power connections and cause electronics to act up.
8. Try using Nouveau Nvidia driver. Nvidia crashes my system in different ways. Older kernel and drives have better Nvidia stability.
9. Try KVM/Qemu and does it still crash
10. Turn off sleep mode on OS, just shut monitor off manually
11. Try older VirtualBox

Let us know if any of these helped figure out the crash issue.